# Checking external session variable on each page before loading, with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, session, cordova

I've created a php login system which saves the username as a session variable, on the server where the php is hosted.

I need to check this session before loading any pages within my stand alone phonegap (html, css & javascript) project which is hosted separately.

Is there a javascript call I can make at the start of each page to check it and then redirect it if they aren't logged in?

Answer (score 0):

you should not do that, somebody could turn off javascript and bypass your check.

instead, do normal php check on eatch page. you can put check into separate file (say, check.php) and just put on etach page `require ('check.php');`

EDIT (reply to comment/question edit):

a) how to make your own session:

as simple as `session_start();`

b) how to pair it with remote session:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['remoteid']))
$_SESSION['remoteid'] = sesion id that you recived as response prom remote php server.
```

once again, you can not do it simply with html, css & javascript. javascript can be turned off. you need php/python/ruby/etc...
needless to add that javascript can not be persistent, since it is not executed on server.

Comment: the application I'm creating has to use javascript, html & css. I'm using phonegap therefore the PHP files are hosted on a separate server.

Comment: so just make your own session and pair it with remote one. you shoud never do any security checks/sanitation/etc. with javascript. ever.

Comment: I don't know what that means, if I did, I probably would've done it.

Comment: what is it that you did not understod?

Comment: thank you for your update, however I need my phonegap application to only use html/javascript. I can have php on a separate server but not within that project.